# 'list' object is not callable on python code where it definitely should be

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Is this really a syntax issue? Did I just not import the right libraries?

```
eps_intervals = 20
max_pts = 10

num_clusters = np.zeros((eps_intervals, max_pts))

for i in range(1, eps_intervals):
    for j in range(max_pts):
        DBSCAN_model = DBSCAN(eps = i * 0.05, min_samples = j)
        DBSCAN_model.fit(Xs)
        num_clusters[i,j] = DBSCAN_model.labels_.max() + 1
```

Produces the following error:

```
----> 6 for i in range(1, eps_intervals):
  7     for j in range(max_pts):
  8         DBSCAN_model = DBSCAN(eps = i * 0.05, min_samples = j)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: try `print(range)`  ... I suspect somewhere above you have something like `range=[1,5]` that shadows the builtin range

Comment: No, it isn't a syntax issue. It *isn't telling you* that it's a syntax issue. That's what `SyntaxError` is for.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere prior to the code you posted, you have assigned some list to the variable `range`, shadowing the built-in function of the same name. But you're still trying to call it like it's that function. As the error message says, you can't call a list.

Don't use the names of built-in functions for variables, especially if you want to use the functions.

Comment: It's a very small notebook. Just looked through and no variable called range

Comment: @lanceparth At any point in your notebook did you use a wildcard import?

Comment: It's also possible you did it at some earlier point and then deleted that code or cell. If you don't have any `from package import *` lines, then restart your kernel.